# Shorter version of this if statement

Tags: php

I have the following:

```
$first = $index % 2 == 0 ? 'partial_one' : 'partial_two';
$last = $index % 2 == 0 ? 'partial_two' : 'partial_one';
```

I have a feeling there is a shorter way to do this. Anyone?

Comment: There is other community for this type of question, take a look of http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It look pretty short from here

Comment: Are the partial texts from an explode command?

Comment: Shorter than a short conditional?

Comment: Well, it can be made even shorter... but I don't really see why.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that...

Comment: Since it's `modulo 2` which only returns 1 or 0, you can just leave out `== 0`, but need to reverse the two strings on each line.

Comment: You could do this. I don't recommend it. `$first = ($a && ($last = ($a = $index % 2 == 0) ? 'partial_one' : 'partial_two')) ? 'partial_two' : 'partial_one';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not shorter, but in my opinion more readable:

```
if ($index % 2 == 0) {
    $first = 'partial_one';
    $last = 'partial_two';
}
else {
    $first = 'partial_two';
    $last = 'partial_one';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I went for this answer in the end, and also Paul's suggestion to get rid of == 0. Thanks for your responses, everyone!